# Confusion regarding the son of God

Tags: nature-of-god, virgin-mary, christology, life-of-jesus

I myself am not a Christian but Iin college I have a Christian Friend. I know that Christians regard Christ as son of God spiritually not bodily. I asked my friend, "Why do you call Eesa (Christ) (Peace be upon him) as the son of God?" He asked me a question in reply "Do you accept that Maryam (Peace be upon her) is his mother?" I said "Yes, indeed." He then said "Had there been anyone father of Eesa from the humans?" I said "No, never ever!" He then said, "Here is the point. He had no father among the humans so by convention we call him the son of God because He has no other father!" My question is, do all the Christians think like this? Was what he saying Christian ideology or simply his ideology? I am not trying to offend anyone. I am asking this question for clarity of my mind and I may clear his mind as well about his religion according to your thoughts so that he may get some more knowledge about his religion.

Comment: I have looked at that and that doesn't answer my questio.

Comment: Re: "I know that Christians regard Christ as son of God spiritually not bodily." This is incorrect. I don't personally know any Christians that hold to this. You'll find that Orthodox, Catholic, mainline Protestant, Pentecostal, and non-denominational Christians nearly unanimously agree that Jesus is _really_ the Son of God, in spirit, body, and every other conceivable way.

Comment: Rehan, this has been marked as a duplicate of another question, but you're saying it doesn't answer your question. Since that's the case, you should [edit] your question to specify how it differs from the other, and point out what you're asking that's not addressed in answers to the other questions.

Comment: Generally, when a Christian says that Jesus is the "Son of God" they are referring to the doctrine of the [Trinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trinity), where Jesus is a person of a three-part godhead. It's a complicated doctrine that necessitates [antinomy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antinomy). As for your friend's reasoning, it is sound, and is the same reason we call Adam, from Genesis, the son of God also, for he also had no human father, instead God fashioned him from the clay of the Earth and breathed life into him.

Comment: @fredsbend Thank You for your answer. But I'll ask you another question in the comments. If Adam and Jesus are sons of God because they did not have father among humans, then what would you say about artificially produced clones who also don't have fathers but only mothers? As the dolly sheep was produced in 1990s, in the same way humans can be produced without fathers. So shall we call them sons of God? if you dont know about artificial cloning look here http://www.bbc.co.uk/schools/gcsebitesize/science/add_gateway_pre_2011/living/cloningrev3.shtml

Comment: @fredsbend For details of cloning look here http://www.animalresearch.info/en/medical-advances/timeline/cloning-dolly-the-sheep/

Comment: @RehanUllah Cloning is a modern invention. The phrase "son of God" in an ancient idea, before cloning was even a consideration. Adam is called a "son of God" because it is part of his identity, just like Isaac is a son of Abraham. The ancient people's needed to say Adam was the son of someone, and only God made sense. To most Christians, Jesus is called *the* Son of God because it is who he is: The Person of the Trinity.

Comment: So I would not apply ancient colloquialisms to modern concepts. The best response for the question of who a clone's father is, is "He is a clone; he has no father."

Comment: @fredsbend Here your answer sounds meaningless. A true religion depends not on the course of time. Its teachings are always universal to all humanity after it. Its ideas never become ancient and are applicable in any century. How can you call the clones of today fatherless? People want to know Who is their father? If you call Jesus son of God, then people today may call clones sons of God as well. What will be your answer because according to Christianity, you wont be able to blame them.

Comment: @fredsbend As long as Trinity is concerned. What would you say about Christians who don't believe in Trinity. For example Arian Christianity, The Mormons, The Ebionites and many more of today. Then why do some of them call Jesus as son of God??

Comment: @RehanUllah The cultural use of the phrase "son of God", and even any phrase, is not a teaching of any religion. Words and languages change ("son of God" is a translation, after all). When the bible says "son of God" it was important to the people back then. Today, we would say something more like "created by God". They mean the same thing in this context.

Comment: @RehanUllah I'm not sure what they mean when they call Jesus the "Son of God". That might be a good question to ask in a new post.

Comment: @fredsbend Okay thanks for your priceless support!!

Answer (score 3):

The overwhelming majority of Christians believe that Jesus was the Son of God spiritually, bodily, and every other way. We believe that he was conceived miraculously within the virgin Mary by the power of the Spirit of God, and so God is his father not in only a figurative sense, but concretely. Most Christian groups consider this to be a fundamental doctrine of the Christian faith.

Jesus said he is the Son of God.

> Luke 22:66-71 (NASB) When it was day, the Council of elders of the people assembled, both chief priests and scribes, and they led Him away to their council chamber, saying, “If You are the Christ, tell us.” But He said to them, “If I tell you, you will not believe; and if I ask a question, you will not answer. But from now on the Son of Man will be seated at the right hand of the power of God.” **And they all said, “Are You the Son of God, then?” And He said to them, “Yes, I am.” Then they said, “What further need do we have of testimony? For we have heard it ourselves from His own mouth.”**
>
> Revelation 2:18,26-28 “The Son of God, who has eyes like a flame of fire, and His feet are like burnished bronze, says this... "He who overcomes, and he who keeps My deeds until the end, to him I will give authority over the nations; and he shall rule them with a rod of iron, as the vessels of the potter are broken to pieces, as I also have received authority from My Father; and I will give him the morning star.

The Apostles also taught that Jesus is the Son of God.

> Acts 9:20-22 Now for several days he was with the disciples who were at Damascus, and immediately he [Saul of Tarsus] began to proclaim Jesus in the synagogues, saying, **“He is the Son of God.”** All those hearing him continued to be amazed, and were saying, “Is this not he who in Jerusalem destroyed those who called on this name, and who had come here for the purpose of bringing them bound before the chief priests?” But Saul kept increasing in strength and confounding the Jews who lived at Damascus by proving that this Jesus is the Christ.
>
> 1 John 5:5 Who is the one who overcomes the world, but he who believes that **Jesus is the Son of God?**

---

Regarding the OP's comment: I took a look at [the site you linked to](https://carm.org/religious-movements/islam/jesus-cannot-be-gods-son), which I have visited before. I disagree with their statement, "nowhere in the Bible does it say that God had relations with anyone to produce a literal son, nor has Christianity taught that God produced a son through any physical act whatsoever."

While the scriptures do not describe any act of intercourse, the teaching of which would be considered obscene, the Scriptures do indeed teach that God *did* act, by which he caused Mary to conceive. She did not only become spiritually pregnant, but physically pregnant with the Son of God, as God told her that she would. Mary was obedient and consented, and so she has been blessed among all women.

> Luke 1:31-38  And behold, **you will conceive** in your womb and bear a son, and you shall name Him Jesus. He will be great and will be called **the Son of the Most High**; and the Lord God will give Him the throne of His father David; and He will reign over the house of Jacob forever, and His kingdom will have no end.” Mary said to the angel, “How can this be, since I am a virgin?” The angel answered and said to her, “**The Holy Spirit will come upon you, and the power of the Most High will overshadow you; and for that reason the holy Child shall be called the Son of God.** And behold, even your relative Elizabeth has also conceived a son in her old age; and she who was called barren is now in her sixth month. For nothing will be impossible with God.” And Mary said, “Behold, the bondslave of the Lord; **may it be done to me** according to your word.” And the angel departed from her.

Jesus did not teach that he was only the Son of God in a spiritual sense, and the Apostles taught us that he was the Son of God without any qualification. That is what we first heard and believed.

Comment: Thank You. Have a look to this well reputed Christian site. It declares that Jesus is not bodily son of God and that God cant have literal offspring. https://carm.org/religious-movements/islam/jesus-cannot-be-gods-son

Comment: @RehanUllah Please see the edited answer. If you would like to discuss this in chat, I would be happy to do that.

Comment: I would like to ask you in chat in details... How can I?

Comment: @Rehan You need 20 reputation to join a chat room. That is pretty easy to do - you are half the way there already.

Comment: @Andrew Okay I'll try to get there.